How in livewire action to path ID parameter which has string literals?
In laravel 10 app / livewire I got error
livewire.js?id=44144c23:1123 Alpine Expression Error: Unexpected token '>'
Expression: "$wire.markAsRead($notification->id)"

clicking on button with notification ID parameter as :
wire:click="markAsRead($notification->id)

I suppose that is raised as for notification is not integer value, but string also
I tried to wrap parameter with "'" :
wire:click="markAsRead('$notification->id')"

But in this literal value as passed :
$notification->id

How have I to pass the parameter ?

wire:click is executed from the browser side, so the parameter value must be printed from the backend side using {{ }} to allow JS to access it:
wire:click="markAsRead({{ $notification->id }})"

{{-- or with quotes if you need a string --}}
wire:click="markAsRead('{{ $notification->id }}')"

